# Setting Stroke on Line causing Anti-Virus to Stop Compilation

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, line, antivirus

I am working on a simple home project that will draw lines on a canvas.  I was working away fine, when all of a sudden my anti-virus protection started throwing up warning messages every time I tried to build.  The project fails to build with the error:

> Error     Could not copy "obj\Debug\Mozieart.exe" to
>   "bin\Debug\Mozieart.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. Mozieart

I am using the latest version of Norton 360 (up to date).  The warning from the anti-virus gives the following information:

- Threat name: SAPE.Heur.AE935
- File name: mozieart.exe (that's the exe that I am trying to build).
- Threat Type: Heuristic Virus.  Detection of a threat based on malware heuristics.

I don't know if this is important but I managed to back-track and narrow it down to the following lines of code:

```
private void RunMeshButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TrizieartMesher mesher = new TrizieartMesher(new Rect(MainImage.RenderSize));

    EdgeCountText.Text = $"{mesher.Edges.Count()}";

    MainCanvas.Children.Clear();
    foreach (IMeshEdge edge in mesher.Edges)
    {
        Line edgeLine = new Line();
        edgeLine.X1 = edge.P1.X;
        edgeLine.Y1 = edge.P1.Y;
        edgeLine.X2 = edge.P2.X;
        edgeLine.Y2 = edge.P2.Y;

        //edgeLine.Stroke = Brushes.MediumOrchid;

        MainCanvas.Children.Add(edgeLine);
    }
}
```

when I have the edgeLine.Stroke line commented out the anti-virus does not complain at all, but as soon as I uncomment that line I get an anti-virus warning and the project fails to compile.

I also tried setting the stroke using an XAML style instead of doing it in the code behind:

```
<Canvas Name="MainCanvas" Background="Transparent" AllowDrop="True">
    <!--<Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Line">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="MediumOrchid" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2.0" />
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Resources>-->
</Canvas>
```

As soon as I uncomment the Canvas Resources I get the anti-virus warning and the project fails to build.

Perhaps I am being paranoid but I am quite worried by this.  Could something be trying to inject a virus into my program when I use the Stroke property of a Line?

Comment: Note that "Heuristic" means Norton did not identify a known virus in your program, but it saw some common pattern in the code that it thinks is "virus like". Personally I would assume Norton is being a little too aggressive and just tell it to ignore your program. Maybe someone else has more information.

Comment: @Quantic I would rather try and change my program so that it doesn't look like a virus.  I did some experiments and was able to build a test program that sets the Line.Stroke with no issues.  I also excluded a large chunk of my program and it compiles with the Line.Stroke in the code.  I will continue to re-arrange it to see if I can get it to work.  Any advice on the best ways to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to stop the anti-virus from detecting something that looks like a virus I had to refactor the code slightly:

```
private void RunMeshButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TrizieartMesher mesher = new TrizieartMesher(new Rect(MainImage.RenderSize));
    EdgeCountText.Text = $"{mesher.Edges.Count()}";

    MainCanvas.Children.Clear();
    List<Line> meshLines = mesher.Edges.Select(edge => CreateLine(edge.P1, edge.P2)).ToList();
    foreach (Line line in meshLines)
    {
        MainCanvas.Children.Add(line);
    }
}

private static Line CreateLine(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    Line newLine = new Line();
    newLine.X1 = p1.X;
    newLine.Y1 = p1.Y;
    newLine.X2 = p2.X;
    newLine.Y2 = p2.Y;

    newLine.Stroke = Brushes.MediumOrchid;

    return newLine;
}
```